# When using Firefox tools to inspect elements html only covering approx 85% of page width?

Tags: html, css, width, screen, containers

CSS:

```
html {
  width:100%;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0;
  float:left;
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

I center my main container to find that it's all a bit to the left because my html container won't go the full width of my computer screen, any ideas based off my code?

Answer (score 0):

Change (or append) `html` to `body` in your css. Both Firefox and Chrome Debuggers show no inheritance from `html` to `body`, except for the `list-style-type`.

```
html, body {
    //Code here
}
```

or

```
body {
    //Code here
}
```

Also a small note, `0px` should just be `0`.

Comment: Hey this didn't help much but I managed to get it working in the end, still a tad unsure how though! Thanks for the support :)